# playsound package to play sound in python

Tags: python, playsound

the code:

```py
from playsound import playsound
playsound("C:\Users\Code Red\Desktop\alarm clock\anotherlove.mp3")
```

output:

```
File "c:\Users\Code Red\Desktop\alarm clock\alarm-clock-using-python.py", line 3
    playsound("C:\Users\Code Red\Desktop\alarm clock\anotherlove.mp3")

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with your file path. Rather than using an absolute path, try to put the sound file in the directory of your code and run with:

```
playsound("anotherlove.mp3")
```

Worked for me on mac. It might have issues with spaces within folder names. Try avoiding that.